# Call base prototype function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypejs, polymorphism

I have the following 2 objects:

```
function circle(radius){
    this.radius = radius;    
    this.foo = function (){
        return "circle foo";};    
    return true;}

function pizza(){
    this.foo = function (){
        return "pizza foo";};
    return true;}

pizza.prototype = new circle(9);
```

When I do the following

```
var foo = myPizza.foo();
```

It prints the following as expected:

> pizza foo

How can I activate the base class and print "circle foo" from `myPizza` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pizza.prototype.foo.call(myPizza);   // outputs "circle foo"
```